# Issue with sales process 'slds-is-Complete' state

Tags: slds

With help of slds sales process as specified in the link:

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/process/#flavor-sales-path-coach-different-coaching

I'm trying to build my own process path. I'm getting CSS issue when i changes the li class from 'slds-in-incomplete' to 'slds-in-complete', i'm getting issue with arrow symbol as specifed in below screen shot.

[image]

If you can observe the image, there is an issue with arrow symbol of 2nd option which is not in green color state. When i inspected the respective element, it was the element of the 3rd option.

Any help?

```
<div class="slds-grid">
  <div class="slds-tabs--path" role="application">
    <ul class="slds-tabs--path__nav" role="tablist">
      <li class="slds-tabs--path__item slds-is-complete" role="presentation">
        <a class="slds-tabs--path__link" id="tabs-path-91" aria-controls="content-path-1" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="tab" href="javascript:void(0);" aria-live="assertive">
          <span class="slds-tabs--path__stage">
              <lightning:icon iconName="utility:check"  size="small" alternativeText="Custom Questions" class="slds-m-right--medium"/>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Stage Complete</span>
          </span>
          <span class="slds-tabs--path__title">Contacted</span>
        </a>
      </li>

        <li class="slds-tabs--path__item slds-is-complete" role="presentation">
            <a class="slds-tabs--path__link" id="tabs-path-92" aria-controls="content-path-1" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="tab" href="javascript:void(0);" aria-live="assertive">
                <span class="slds-tabs--path__stage">
                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:check"  size="small" alternativeText="Custom Questions 1" class="slds-m-right--medium"/>
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Stage Complete</span>
                </span>
                <span class="slds-tabs--path__title">Open</span>
            </a>
        </li> 

        <li class="slds-tabs--path__item slds-is-incomplete" role="presentation">
            <a class="slds-tabs--path__link" id="tabs-path-94" aria-controls="content-path-1" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="tab" href="javascript:void(0);" aria-live="assertive">
                <span class="slds-tabs--path__stage" aria-hidden="true">
                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:check"  size="small" alternativeText="Custom Questions 2" class="slds-m-right--medium"/>
                </span>
                <span class="slds-tabs--path__title">Nurturing</span>
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul></div></div>
```

Comment: Why do you implement your own `Path`? isn't the new [Path](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_sales_features_core_path_expanded.htm) component good enough for custom objects?

Comment: @ItaiShmida My requirement is to implement the same in custom component (lightning).